# How to create a see-through triangle?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a navbar with a triangle cutout. I put together an example so you can see what I am after:

http://www.volinux.org/test3

As you see, I used the border hack in this case to create my triangle, however it is unusable because the navbar has a background image. I have tried to implement many alternatives using countless examples on the web, such as SVG or rotating div with counter-rotating an inside div with a background to create the triangle, however I wasn't successful in having something solid.

The closest I came to achieving this effect was indeed with the rotating trick and a background-attachment: fixed, but this does not work in my case as you immediately notice the flaw when you start to scroll up and down the page.

I hope one of you can point me in the right direction. It does not matter if it is SVG, CSS3 or whatever, but it must work on all browsers starting from the IE9 era and above, and it must be rock solid.

I look forward to any suggestions.

I added a sketch of what I am trying to achieve:

http://www.volinux.org/test3/IMG_0646.jpg

Comment: Broken link (http://www.volinux.org/test3)

Comment: best update that link and post a sample of the code you're working with.

Comment: No... not broken. But it took quite a while to be visible across all servers. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with SVG by creating mask with that small triangle. Here is an example:

```
<svg>
<defs>
    <rect id='tri-bar' width='100%' height='20'/>
    <mask id='tri-mask'>
        <use xlink:href='#tri-bar' fill='white'/>
        <polygon points='0 20, 10 10, 20 20' x='50' fill='black'/>
    </mask>
</defs>

<use xlink:href='#tri-bar' fill='gray' mask='url(#tri-mask)'/>
```

For moving that triangle `transform` property with `translate(x,y)` should be used.

```
<polygon transform='translate(50,0)' points='0 20, 10 10, 20 20' x='50' fill='black' />
```

So, for each animation frame `(x,y)` should be overwritten.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eF8LW/1/)

Comment: This works for me, if I can now somehow add navigation items via an unordered list and align that triangle to the center of the list items. Can you expand your fiddle with this?

Comment: I have forked your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/billy2020/W6vf8/

The translate animation is not a problem, now I just need to align the initial triangle to one of the list items.

Comment: For alignment get the position of your item and add some value. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/W6vf8/1/. Initialy I thought to add the half of the itme size, but then I found that it looks not so good.

Comment: Yup, my bad, the text was not centered and had to deduct half the width of the triangle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Kvgk6/

All in all I have a working solution. But I presume there no way to align the triangle if javascript is disabled?

Comment: Nice. I, personaly, do not know some methods to do alignmet without javascript.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Thanks vz_ ! You've helped me with an impossible task.

Answer (score 0):

set to that element the following style:

```
background: transparent;
```

Comment: Someone flagged this as low quality. Consider adding somewhat of an explanation.

Comment: Please see the link to understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: yup, I did, sorry, my bad

Comment: @user3097651 take a look at CSS Masking

Comment: @Mr. Alien, thanks, I already have. But I lack the necessary skills to implement it. If you are able to assist, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @Mr. Alien, according to my tests with CSS Masks, there is no consistent and viable solution that works across all browsers

Comment: @user3097651 yes obviously it wont, CSS is not that capable in these things yet

Comment: @Mr. Alien, why do you suggest it then?

Comment: @user3097651 use a background png image

Comment: @Mr. Alien, background pngs aren't fluid. As soon as the width of the link changes (multi-lingual), the png is off.